# how to parse xml tags in iphone

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing

i have xml tag like this.

```
<rule_heading>
Add 
<rule_heading_italic>ing</rule_heading_italic>
 when the verb ends in . . . 
</rule_heading>
```

when i parse rule_heading tag it adds "when the verb ends in..." only.
i want to add the data between the rule_heading starting and ending tag.
how can i do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is this through NSXMLParser?

The should be parsed as two different text blocks, I believe.

Comment: I don't believe that NSXMLParser will handle the case requested above. The requested case is something that violates standard XML parsing rules.  The NSXMLParser calls the delegate with a stream of begin and end element notifications and notifications for inter-element text.  One could piece together the string using those, but it wouldn't be pretty.

Comment: which parser can i use to handle the above case.